# Save changes on a DB after edit a grid

Tags: database, vb.net, gridview

I want to save some changes in a database trough a datagridview by clicking on a button. Basically that same button must make the changes that I want (on the code  below with loops) and save them automatically but it doesn't work.

Can you please see what's wrong? I think that is something about the update line. I created the update string on the tableadapter command in the design view. If you need more code just ask me. The commented lines are some tests that I am doing.

If change the cell after editing, it saves. I used the `DGV5_SelectionChanged` event. Thank you

```
Public Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = DGV1(5, 0).Value

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'loop para preencher a coluna do potencial de prescrição.... = 5 

    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 1
        Select Case DGV3(2, i).Value
            Case 26
                DGV3(9, i).Value = 8

        End Select
    Next
    DoctorEnterpriseDetailsTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorEnterpriseDetails)

    'Loop para nr de clinicas

    For i = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 2
        For j = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2

            'guardar nas observações
            If Trim(DGV1(20, i).Value.ToString) = "" Then

                DGV1(20, i).Value = checknull(DGV5(6, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(7, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(8, j).Value.ToString)

            Else

                DGV1(20, i).Value = checknull(DGV1(20, i).Value) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & checknull(DGV5(6, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(7, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(8, j).Value.ToString)

            End If

            DGV1(13, i).Value = 0
        Next
    Next
    DoctorBasicTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorBasic)

    'loop para a selecção (EnterpriseDetails) id 8 para nao aplicavel

    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 1

        Select Case DGV3(2, i).Value 'lusovencor
            Case 26
                DGV3(5, i).Value = 48

        End Select
    Next
    DoctorEnterpriseDetailsTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorEnterpriseDetails)

    ' loop para a morada - Funciona!

    For j = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2
        DGV5(6, j).Value = "NÃO DEFINIDO" ' para a morada
        DGV5(7, j).Value = 421705           'para o codigo postal
        DGV5(8, j).Value = 0            'para o tipo local
        DGV5(9, j).Value = ""   ' para o horário
        DGV5(10, j).Value = True   ' visto para o LocalVisita

    Next
    DoctorsAddressTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorsAddress)

    ' loop perfil clinico - Funciona

    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 2

        Select Case DGV3(2, i).Value
            Case 26
                DGV3(23, i).Value = 8

        End Select

    Next
    DoctorEnterpriseDetailsTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorEnterpriseDetails)

    'loop categoria - medicos

    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 2
        Select Case DGV3(2, i).Value
            Case 26
                DGV3(6, i).Value = 84

        End Select

    Next
    DoctorEnterpriseDetailsTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorEnterpriseDetails)

    'sqlConnection1.Open()
    'GSM81DataSet = DGV1(20, i).Value.DataSource
    'DoctorBasicTableAdapter.Update(GSM81DataSet.DoctorBasic)
    'GSM81DataSet.AcceptChanges()
    ApagarRegistos()
    'sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Comment: in future, please please please use a proper naming convention. It makes it near-impossible to understand what the stuff is doing

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot!

Comment: with time, you'll be giving everything meaningful names. Learning it early is better than learning it too late (from experience). As for your question, I would read something like [this](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_database.htm)

Comment: I will try to change it meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

Here Is a sample program, which allows you to operate CRUD (create/read/update and delete) from a datagrid view:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        save_btn.Enabled = True
        new_btn.Enabled = False
        delete_btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        new_btn.Enabled = True
        delete_btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is allowing basic CRUD operations on a data grid view.

[SOURCE](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_database.htm)

Comment: And what if the database is and acess database? Can I use TableAdpater insead sqlDataAdapter?

Comment: i'm 90% certain that's referring to the sql *language* and not specifically the dbms.